# Why doesn't a healing factor cure cancer?

Tags: comics, deadpool

I've read quite a bit about Deadpool, up to the point I know he has cancer, and that he has a healing factor. I don't quite get why one doesn't cancel the other out. I know that in Deadpool's case he had the cancer first, but is that the important part?

Likewise, I assume Wolverine has never and could never contact cancer, due to his healing factor which is much stronger than Deadpools.

Is there a discrepancy here? Should a healing factor cure Wade's cancer? Or is he a special case for some reason? For some reason I can't seem to get my brain 'round this.

[image: Deadpool clutching his head, and shouting "You have failed me, brain!"]

Comment: TL;DR: his cancer has a healing factor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cancer isn't a disease or externally-caused problem like a broken bone:  It's [unregulated growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer) of the body's own cells.  No matter how good you are at healing yourself, you'd be attacking your own body to kill off the cancer cells.

If anything, I'd expect a healing factor to cause *more* cancer.

Comment: Despite being a biochemist, cancer is unbelievably uninteresting to me, but despite this, from what I recall many of the tumor suppressor genes they initiate apoptosis on cells which may not necessarily turn cancerous.  If you don't have these anti-oncogenes, you may get some (imperceptible, but everything's amplified in the comic-book world) increase in vigor.

Comment: We can even think of the healing factor itself as a form of cancer, or an abnormal and rapid replication of cells. Deadpool's healing factor might be a little more out of control than Wolverine's.

Comment: does that mean Wolverine is eventually going to get arthritis?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Some other question/answer on here has established that Wolverine is aging, just extremely slowly.  So yep!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, Deadpool is a special case. His healing factor works well because the cancer is a degenerative one; it removes the cells of his body at roughly the same rate that his healing factor replaces them. The Skrulls tried to use his healing in *Secret Invasion*. They failed miserably because the healing is overpowered, spending much of its energy in continuously counteracting Deadpool's cancer. Without the cancer to keep it in check, it effectively acts as a rapid cancer of its own, overrunning the body.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, deadpool did have cancer before he received his healing factor. However, once it kicked in it accelerated his cancer throughout his body.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Deadpool got cancer before getting the healing factor.
The healing factor of his was artificially mutated into him on purpose to fight his cancer. And I thought it did.

Answer (score 0):

Deadpool's healing factor and his cancer work against each other. Like a stalemate. Neither is strong enough to overcome the other. The healing factor keeps Deadpool alive and symptom free aside from the face issue.